# Accessing barometer data from Lumia 1020

Tags: c#, windows-phone, altitude

Apparently the Lumia 1020 has a barometer. See the "Extra Features" section in the link below.

http://developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/Lumia_1020/

I would like to know how to access elevation data directly from the barometer. Right now I have access to elevation data from the `Geolocator` object in the `Windows.Devices.Geolocation` namespace, but it's giving me back elevation from the GPS signal, not from the barometer. I know this because the `Geolocator` object's `Altitude` property varies by tens of meters while at constant elevation over a period of minutes while the phone is just sitting on the table.  The barometer should vary on the order of centimeters.

Any ideas? Perhaps it will just be a matter of time before we can see an update in the Windows Phone SDK?

Comment: I haven't used the 1020 nor tried a device with a barometer but have you set the Geolocator's [DesiredAccuracy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.positionaccuracy) property to `High`? This might determine whether or not to use the Barometer for accuracy.

Comment: Good idea, but already tried that.

Comment: @user1950470 you have peeked my interest. I am looking into this.

Comment: The Galaxy Nexus has a barometer too, but it's *only* used to feed a known piece of data into the GPS to obtain a lock faster (one less variable to solve for). It is completely unavailable for any other use. I suspect that it's the same for this device.

Answer (score 2):

The Galaxy Nexus has a barometer too, but it's *only* used to feed a known piece of data into the GPS to obtain a lock faster (one less variable to solve for). It is completely unavailable for any other use. I suspect that it's the same for this device. Why would you need barometer altitude when you have GPS?

Here's a reference for the Nexus: http://www.engadget.com/2011/10/20/galaxy-nexus-barometer-explained-sam-champion-not-out-of-a-job/

*Well...* "It's there, why not make it available?" was my question when I learned of this.

Comment: There are benefits in using the barometer please refer to this article.

https://strava.zendesk.com/entries/20965883-Elevation-for-Your-Activity

Answer (score 2):

You can found information about barometer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.sensors.barometer) but as I know the api available only in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6. You can found example project [on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/barometer)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it can't be accessed by the Windows Phone 8 API and is apparently only used to feed the GPS data to speed up detection: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/510c700e-85a2-49e2-9861-1c35b4714403/how-to-access-barometer-sensor-of-lumia-1020?forum=wpdevelop

Here's a list of the supported sensors for Windows Phone 8 API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx